# Matching repetition with capturing groups returns only the final match value

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to capture a recursive sequence using matching repetition with capturing groups.

Here is a sample text:

```
some_string_here  00  12.34  34  56.78  78.90
```

The regexp used to capture all the floating point values:

```
\S+(?:\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)){5}
```

The regexp matches all the floating point values as expected but the capturing group returns only the final match result.

```
Group #1: 78.90
```

The required result is:

```
Group #1: 00
Group #2: 12.34
Group #3: 34
Group #4: 56.78
Group #5: 78.90
```

If I use the following as the regexp, the result is as expected, but with too many recursive sequence, the regexp is too long.

```
\S+(?:\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?))(?:\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?))(?:\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?))(?:\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?))(?:\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?))
```

Is there a way to capture all of the floating point values in a matching repetition with capturing groups?

Comment: What do you mean by *“the regexp is too long”*?

Comment: This is the way Perl regexes work. With only one pair of parentheses there can be only one capture. It looks like you should just use `split`

Comment: @Akshay Belvadi Your regex is repeat `(?:\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?))` 6 times will be wrong with `some_string_here  00  12.34  34  56.78  78.90 78.90` (7 numbers) `/(?:\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?))/g` will work too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$s = "some_string_here  00  12.34  34  56.78  78.90";
@ar = $s =~m/(\d+\.?(?:\d+)?)/g;
$, = "\n";
print @ar;
```

`g` flag returns all possible matches in a list. And the list was stored into the array. So it will give the all possible matches in an array.

Without using `g` global modifier it returns the only one element that is `00`. Because search will satisfy at a first match.

output

```
00
12.34
34 
56.78
78.90
```

Else you want to store particular number of elements, create the list and the give the variables

For example, you want to store the only three matches,

```
($first,$second,$thrid) = $s =~m/(\d+\.?(?:\d+)?)/g;
```

Here `$first holds the 00, $second holds the 12.34 and the $third holds the 34.`

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, you probably just want [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html), like this

```
my $s = 'some_string_here  00  12.34  34  56.78  78.90';

my @groups = split ' ', $s;
shift @groups;

for my $i ( 0 .. $#groups ) {
    printf "Group #%d: %-s\n", $i+1, $groups[$i];
}
```

#### output

```
Group #1: 00
Group #2: 12.34
Group #3: 34
Group #4: 56.78
Group #5: 78.90
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(\d+\.?\d*)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uX2hF2/1)

Input

```
some_string_here  00  12.34  34  56.78  78.90
```

Output

```
MATCH 1
1.  [18-20] `00`
MATCH 2
1.  [22-27] `12.34`
MATCH 3
1.  [29-31] `34`
MATCH 4
1.  [33-38] `56.78`
MATCH 5
1.  [40-45] `78.90`
```